# Rails update enum fields is not a valid

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I am trying to update a form but I am getting the following error when submitting it.

> 'accepted' is not a valid status

in my `pdform.rb` model I have this enum

```
enum status: { submitted: 0, approved: 1, rejected: 2 }
```

This is the input for the status. I have tried switching around the second accepted to the value in the enum but when I do that I get this error.

```
<div class="form-group row">
    <%= form.label :status, class: 'col-2 col-form-label' %>
    <div class="col-md-5">
      <%= form.select(:status, options_for_select([['Accepted', 'accepted'], ['Declined', 'declined']]), { include_blank: true }) %>
    </div>
  </div>
```

> '1' is not a valid status

In my schema file for the forms table I have the default status set to be 0, but when I submit this form it comes out as nil. Do I need to switch over the status to a string and set the default to 'submitted'? How can I update this form without getting that error?

```
t.integer "status", default: 0
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your option values are  **accepted, declined** which is not mentioned in enum status.

So, either add them in enum

> enum status: { submitted: 0, approved: 1, rejected: 2, accepted: 3,
>   declined: 4 }

**or**

change form select option to contain only those values that are in enum

```
  <%= form.select(:status, options_for_select([['Submitted',
 'submitted'],['Approved','approved'],['Rejected','rejected']]), {
 include_blank: true }) %>
```

Comment: @TrentonTyler  happens.   If found my solutions useful. Upvote. Thank YOU

Comment: Adding the `accepted` and `declined` options in the `enum` is correct. Though, other suitable way would be

`enum status: [:submitted, :approved, :rejected, :accepted, :declined]`

Setting the `enum` as array would assign it the array index automatically. You can always change the order.

and use `form.select :status, Model.statuses.keys.map {|u| [u.titleize, u]}` instead. I think its much cleaner.

Comment: @Aakanksha yes both way works. Good to know you again. :)